# Expectation of time to reach 0

Tags: probability, expected-value

The problem starts with sampling from a discrete uniform $\{0,\dots,N-1\}$. After getting the first random number $x_1$, sample $x_2$ from an updated uniform $\{0,\dots,x_1\}$, and go on until we get a sample equal $0$. The question is computing the expected number of sampling times until seeing the $0$.

It seems relevant to coupon collection problems and needs the linearity of expectation and indicator functions, but I cannot clearly formulate it. Please help. Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think linearity and indicator variables come into it at all.  It's just conditional expectation.

This is a rewrite of my earlier answer.  I hadn't understood that the number drawn is replaced, unless it is $0$.

Let $E_n$ be the expected number of draws required if the highest number is $n$, so that $E_0=1.$  Then
$$\begin{align}
E_1&= \frac12 +\frac12(1+E_1)\implies E_1=2\\
E_2&=\frac13+\frac13(1+E_1)+\frac13(1+E_2)\implies E_2=\frac52\\
&\vdots\\
E_n&=1+\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E_k\implies\\
\frac n{n+1}E_n&=1+\frac1{n+1}\sum{k=1}^nE_k\implies\\
E_n&=\frac{n+1}n+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E_k
\end{align}$$

If we now write $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nE_k$ then the last equation can be written as $$S_n-S_{n-1}=\frac{n+1}{n}+\frac1nS_{n-1}$$ so we get the simple recurrence
$$S_n=\frac{n+1}{n}(1+S_{n-1})\tag1$$  It's easiest to compute the $S_n$ from $(1)$ and then compute $E_n$ as $S_n-S{n-1}$, I think.

The simple form of $(1)$ leads one to hope for an explicit solution, but I haven't been able to find one.

**EDIT**

One can see that $$E_n=\frac{a_n}{n!}$$ where $a_n$ comes from [A000774](http://oeis.org/A000774) of OIES. Since no formula is given there for $a_n$, it seems unlikely that an explicit formula can be found easily.

Comment: I think it has to be $f(0) = 0 \hspace{50pt} f(1) = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty (\frac12)^j = 2 \hspace{30pt} f(n) = 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac1k f(k) \hspace{10pt} \forall n \in \mathbb N_{>1}$. I don't know how to solve this and Wolfram doesn't understand the input

Comment: @silver I think you must mean $f(n) = 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac1nf(k)$  but even then, there's a problem, since the sum of the probabilities is $>1$.  Probably you mean the upper limit of summation to be $n-1$

Comment: should have been $\sum_{k =0}^n \frac1{n+1}f(k)$

Comment: @silver Then it seems to be the same thing I said.  Just a difference in notation, I think.

Comment: @saulspatz and silver, Thanks a lot for the help! The idea of thinking from the smallest number to the general number really helps~

Comment: @SandroS You're welcome.  If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark, so that it no longer shows as unresolved.

Comment: @saulspatz I just tried to review a little on paper, and then realized some confusion. For the first equation I suppose for the case of sampling from $\{0,1\}$, 1/2 we get $0$ and 1/2 we get $1$, so that $E_1 = 1/2(E_0)+1/2(1+E_1)$ and this leads to $E_1 = 1+ E_0$. What did I mess up?

Comment: @SandroS First of all, we'll never get $E_1$ again.  If we draw ball $0$ the game is over, and if we draw ball $1$ we're in the $E_0$ case.  You should have $E_1 = \frac12\cdot1+\frac12(1+E_0)$

Comment: @saulspatz Isn't it that given $\{0,1\}$ after we draw ball 1, we still have to sample $\{0,1\}$? Only add one more draw. So that it is $1+E_1$. Maybe you assumed it is sampled without replacement?

Comment: @SandroS Yes, I guess I misunderstood the question.  I'll rewrite my answer to take this into account, but I'm expecting a guest any minute, and it will have to wait until later this evening, I'm afraid.  This may be what silver was driving at in his comment.  I'll have to reread that, too.

Comment: @silver I see what you were driving at now.  See if you agree with my rewrite.  It seems to me that the lower index of summation in your last comment should be $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: yeah, now it looks correct. Props for figuring it out even though I didn't follow up after your last comment.

Comment: And the lower index doesn't change the sum since f(0) = 0

Comment: @silver isn't $f(0)=1$?

Comment: I've defined $f(n)$ as the expected number of rolls you need to hit a 0, provided that the current number is $n$. If $n=0$, you've already hit $0$, so the game is already over. (But I can see how this is unnecessarily confusing, it probably would have been clearer to exclude 0.)